# IIS 7 URL Rewrite to sub-site

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

So I have this FTP site set up: "https://docs.site.com"

When one tries to navigate to just the base site it kicks back a 403 forbidden access denied error, which is what it should do.

What I am needing is for when people navigate to the aforementioned address for it to forward to "https://docs.site.com/documents"

/documents is a sub-directory where the web application is and people are able to do what they need to do.

Comment: Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. After adding the HTTP Redirect role I was able to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the web server (IIS) to redirect requests for your root url 'https://docs.site.com' to where you really want them to go 'https://docs.site.com/documents'. See the following steps from [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage (https://docs.site.com).
2. In Features View, double-click HTTP Redirect.
3. On the HTTP Redirect page, select Redirect requests to this destination. In the corresponding box, type the file name, directory path, or URL to which you want to redirect the user (https://docs.site.com/documents).
4. In the Actions pane, click Apply.